# Android Zoomed Imageview Conflict Swipe Gesture with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used [Zoomage](https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage) to implement the zoom feature on my imageview. I have a FragmentPagerAdapter that create each fragment which consist of each zoom imageview.
So my problem is: While the image is zoomed, then I swipe left or right the image does not move to all of the zoom area, but it go to the next image of the viewpager instead.
In short I want to see all the zoomed area on the image when I swipe left/right on the zoom image.
Im sure it might cause from the conflicting of swipe event on zoom image and viewpager but I cannot find any good solution yet. 
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried with [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)?

Comment: @Piyush, thanks for your response, I have seen the library also, I already downloaded the TouchImageView from github, but I don't know to import it to my project. I used to import it as a module and after sync gradle, it cause many error.

Comment: You can just make a separate class from it. Don't need to use that lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used zoom functionality in my project using following ***TouchImageView*** class:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
private Matrix matrix;
// We can be in one of these 3 states
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;
// Remember some things for zooming
private final PointF last = new PointF();
private final PointF start = new PointF();
private float maxScale = 3f;
private float[] m;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private static final int CLICK = 3;
private float saveScale = 1f;
private float origWidth;
private float origHeight;
private int oldMeasuredHeight;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

    super.setClickable(true);

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {

    maxScale = x;

}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        float minScale = 1f;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

private void fixTrans() {

    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}


private float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

    float minTrans, maxTrans;
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;

}

private float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Rescales image on rotation
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;

    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;

        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);
        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;
        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
```

}

In xml file :

```
 <com.enduserapp.utils.customUI.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_splash"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

You can try this

Or you can use [this file](https://gist.github.com/RozinaDarediya/45c713ef4095c8cedc2e9fcce6f94bf6). We are have some limit to write here, so I have given you link of file. It is also working. Let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: I have try with your solution but my imageview is blank now.  I tried to copy your class into my project and used it in xml layout like yours.

Comment: @TouchSreyleak which link did you tried?
Did you try second?

Comment: the link to the txt file, actually it works when I put with static image, but it shows me blank when I used Glide to load image from server into the touchimageview.

Comment: oh now it works, thank you so much!! Sorry that I cannot upvote it because I am a new comer no reputation yet.

Comment: @TouchSreyleak I am glad to help you. You can upvote after getting sufficient reputation. But I think you would be able to accept the answer if correction mark is visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem in my application by defining a zoom-listener interface that use zoom scale value to set viewPager2 isUserInputEnabled function to true in case of scale = 1 and false otherwise.

Zoom listener:

```
interface ZoomListener {
    fun onZoomScaleChanged(scale: Float)
}
```

In zoomable ImageView:

```
class ZoomImageView : AppCompatImageView, View.OnTouchListener,
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
// Image View zoom listener
private var zoomListener: ZoomListener? = null
//shared constructing
private var mContext: Context? = null
private var mScaleDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
private var mGestureDetector: GestureDetector? = null
var mMatrix: Matrix? = null
private var mMatrixValues: FloatArray? = null
var mode = NONE

// Scales
var mSaveScale = 1f
var mMinScale = 1f
var mMaxScale = MAX_SCALE

// view dimensions
var origWidth = 0f
var origHeight = 0f
var viewWidth = 0
var viewHeight = 0
private var mLast = PointF()
private var mStart = PointF()

 ...

    override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        var mScaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor
        val prevScale = mSaveScale
        mSaveScale *= mScaleFactor
        if (mSaveScale > mMaxScale) {
            mSaveScale = mMaxScale
            mScaleFactor = mMaxScale / prevScale
        } else if (mSaveScale < mMinScale) {
            mSaveScale = mMinScale
            mScaleFactor = mMinScale / prevScale
        }
        if (origWidth * mSaveScale <= viewWidth
            || origHeight * mSaveScale <= viewHeight) {
            mMatrix!!.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2.toFloat(),
                viewHeight / 2.toFloat())
        } else {
            mMatrix!!.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                detector.focusX, detector.focusY)
        }
        fixTranslation()
        
        // ===================================
        // Call listener
        zoomListener?.onZoomScaleChanged(mSaveScale)
        return true
    }
}


private  fun fitToScreen() {
    mSaveScale = 1f
    val scale: Float
    val drawable = drawable
    if (drawable == null || drawable.intrinsicWidth == 0 || drawable.intrinsicHeight == 0) return
    val imageWidth = drawable.intrinsicWidth
    val imageHeight = drawable.intrinsicHeight
    val scaleX = viewWidth.toFloat() / imageWidth.toFloat()
    val scaleY = viewHeight.toFloat() / imageHeight.toFloat()
    scale = scaleX.coerceAtMost(scaleY)
    mMatrix!!.setScale(scale, scale)

    // Center the image
    var redundantYSpace = (viewHeight.toFloat()
            - scale * imageHeight.toFloat())
    var redundantXSpace = (viewWidth.toFloat()
            - scale * imageWidth.toFloat())
    redundantYSpace /= 2.toFloat()
    redundantXSpace /= 2.toFloat()
    mMatrix!!.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace)
    origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace
    origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace
    imageMatrix = mMatrix

    // ==========================
    // Call listener with new scale
    zoomListener?.onZoomScaleChanged(mSaveScale)
}

// =============================
// Use this function to set zoom listener callback in pagerView2 fragment
fun setZoomListener(listener: ZoomListener) {
    zoomListener = listener
}
// =============================

// ...
```

}

On pagerView2 fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    binding.zoomableImageView.apply {
        setZoomListener(object: ZoomListener {
            override fun onZoomScaleChanged(scale: Float) {
                // here I call parent fragment viewmModel to set scale
                parentViewModel.onZoomScaleChanged(scale)
            }
        })
    }

    // ...

    return binding.root
}
```

In parent viewModel

```
private val _zoomScaleState: MutableStateFlow<Float> = MutableStateFlow(1f) // no zoom
val zoomScaleState = _zoomScaleState.asStateFlow()

fun onZoomScaleChanged(scale: Float) {
    _zoomScaleState.value = scale
}
```

In Fragment that contains pagerView2

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.zoomScaleState.collect { scale ->
                binding.pager.isUserInputEnabled = scale == 1f
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope I have been helpful and understandable in my code explanation.